# Alimentação da list c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma lista no meu código que é alimentada da seguinte maneira:

```
string Recursos = "E-mail, Desktop, Datasul, Aptus";
            string[] RecursoArray = Regex.Split(Recursos, @"\W+\s+");

            List<Ti01> ListaRecursos = new List<Ti01>();

            Ti01 t1 = new Ti01();

            foreach (var tarefa in RecursoArray)
            {


                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tarefa))
                {

                    t1.Recursos = tarefa;

                    if (tarefa.Equals("Datasul") || tarefa.Equals("Protheus") || tarefa.Equals("Aptus") || tarefa.Equals("SalesForce"))
                    {
                        t1.TipoRecurso = "Sistemas";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        t1.TipoRecurso = "Infra";
                    }


                    if (tarefa.Equals("Datasul"))
                    {
                        t1.ObsRecurso = model.ObsDatasul;
                    }
                    else if (tarefa.Equals("Protheus"))
                    {
                        t1.ObsRecurso = model.ObsProtheus;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        t1.ObsRecurso = "";
                    }

                    ListaRecursos.Add(t1);

                }
```

Porém é adicionado apenas o `ULTIMO` recurso desse foreach.

No caso do exemplo, o recurso `Aptus` seria adicionado a essa lista `4 vezes`, ignorando todos os outros índices.
Alguem tem uma noção do que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Adicione o `Ti01 t1 = new Ti01();` Dentro do `foreach`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que você só cria uma instância do objeto `Ti01()` e fica inserindo ele diversas vezes, apenas alterando as informações.
A palavra-chave `new` tem o papel de criar um novo objeto (ou nova referência) da classe alvo. Como você só está dando um `new`, é como se todos fossem o mesmo objeto. Por exemplo:

```
Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();
pessoa.idade = 20;
List<Pessoa> listaPessoas = new List<Pessoa>();
listaPessoas.add(pessoa);
pessoa.idade = 22; //Altera o objeto pessoa que está na lista
listaPessoas.add(pessoa); //Adiciona mais uma referência ao mesmo objeto pessoa
```

Por isso parece que só adicionou o último objeto, mas a verdade é que ele só adicionou várias vezes a referência para esse mesmo objeto e alterando os valores do objeto referenciado, dando a sensação de que adicionou apenas o último. Para resolver esse problema, você precisa instanciar um novo objeto (dar um `new`) **a cada iteração do laço**, por exemplo:

```
Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();
pessoa.idade = 20;
List<Pessoa> listaPessoas = new List<Pessoa>();
listaPessoas.add(pessoa);
pessoa = new Pessoa(); //Cria um novo objeto pessoa
pessoa.idade = 22;
listaPessoas.add(pessoa); //Adiciona uma nova referência com outra idade
```

No caso do seu código, só é necessário colocar a linha:

```
Ti01 t1 = new Ti01();
```

Dentro do loop:

```
foreach (var tarefa in RecursoArray)
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo. Tirei o objeto do foreach para implementar novas funções, e acabei não me atentando a isso. Obrigado pela ajuda!!